# The short circuit test on a single phase transformer

Tags: power

In the short circuit test of a single phase transformer, we connect a wattmeter to on the high voltage side and we increase the voltage till rated currents are set up. The text book says that the wattmeter measures the copper losses of transformer at full load. This means that it includes the copper losses of both the winding in which the wattmeter is connected and the winding which is kept shorted. However the wattmeter is connected only to one side like we know. How is it that it accounts for losses on both sides. Im confused and could surely do with some help.

Answer (score 2):

Because the transformer is used to transform voltage level, but the power is still the same. Of course the same but you have to subtract loss. So any secondary load can be measured with wattmeter on primary. In your situation there is no load, rather a short circuit, so delivered load power is zero, what you measure is loss, only.

Answer (score 1):

Any power losses in the secondary winding get supplied via the primary hence, a wattmeter on the primary measures all copper losses in both primary and secondary.